Why $\sum\limits_{x, y \in \mathbb F_q} (x+y)(x-y) = \sum\limits_{a, b \in \mathbb F_q} ab$
Let $q$ be a prime power and $\mathbb F_q$ the finite field with order $q$, why $\sum\limits_{x, y \in \mathbb F_q} (x+y)(x-y) = \sum\limits_{a, b \in \mathbb F_q} ab$?
We can denote $a = x+y$ and $b=x-y$, but I still don't know why the equation above holds.

When $2\nmid q$, we have $f(x,y)=(x+y, x-y)$ is a bijection from $\mathbb F_q^2$ to itself, as it has inverse map $g(a,b)=(\frac{a+b}{2}, \frac{a-b}{2})$. So $(x+y)(x-y)$ is just a permutation of $ab$. This is a useful technique in many questions, but not really for this particular one, since
$$\operatorname{LHS} = \sum_{x,y}x^2-y^2=q(\sum_{x}x^2-\sum_{y}y^2) = 0$$
$$\operatorname{RHS} = \sum_{a,b}ab=(\sum_{a}a)(\sum_{b}b)=(\sum_{a} a)^2=0$$
$\sum_{a} a=0$ because when $a\not=0$, $a\not=-a$, so they cancel each other. Here is an alternative proof for all $q>2$ (that works even if $2\mid q$): $\mathbb F_q$ consists of all roots of $x^q-x$, and the sum of all its roots (up to a sign) is the coefficient of $x^{q-1}$ which is $0$ whenever $q>2$.
However, when $q=2$, the LHS is still $0$, but the RHS is clearly $1$.
